# how to change files titles with java

Tags: java, file-rename

i would like to ask if it is possible with a java prog to give a specific path to a folder "Folder1" and then rename all the files in it, changing each non-word and non-number to whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`FileFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) to filter the files of a Directory and then use [`file.renameTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) to rename the files.